# Doubts about the Zoom's meeting sdk

Tags: zoom-sdk, zoom-meeting

I want to integrate zoom inside my website, using zoom’s meeting sdk, but I am little bit confused as, the documentation [here](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/auth/), says that I need to convert to JWT, but the JWT are now deprecated as said in all the documentation. Please guide me so that I can move forward. I want to let the users schedule the meetings as well as attend them on the website .

I have tried to integrate the sdk in localhost, it was working fine if we have the meeting Id and passcode of already hosted/scheduled meeting, but was not able to host meeting.